# How many IP's can I set in the Azure API Management Policy IP Filter?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I appreciate your help with the following question: How many IP's can I set in the Azure API Management Policy "IP Filter"?

Thank you,

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

There is no such limit towards the number of IP addresses. You can specify address ranges and individual range

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#RestrictCallerIPs

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Portal you can set as much as IP filters you need. API management does not have restriction towards the number of IP addresses. I have tried setting nearly 40 IPs.

You can also specify the range of IPs incase.